# How to import class from dll in chromium gn build

Tags: class, chromium, dllimport, ninja, gn

I have build a dll(syncDemo.dll,syncDemo.lib) which has class and functions.
I add syncDemo.lib into my chromium gn file.
`libs = ["syncDemo.lib"]`
After include .h head file, I can use the function in the .lib.
But when I use the class in the .lib like:
`CSyncDemo* csd = new CSyncDemo();csd->TestDemo();`
the complier fails with error: **unknown type name 'csd'**
Are there some build flag need to be change when import class from dll?
Below is the content of my gn file:

```
static_library("browser") {
     "//build/config:precompiled_headers",
   ]
  defines = [ "ZLIB_CONST" ]
  ...
  sources = [
    ...
    "sync_sdk_win/SyncDemo.h",
  ]
  libs = [ "sync_sdk_win/syncDemo.lib" ]
```

Comment: Would be better if you can show the relevant portion of `GN` file

Comment: Below is the content of my gn file:
`static_library("browser") {
     "//build/config:precompiled_headers",
   ]
  defines = [ "ZLIB_CONST" ]
  ...
  sources = [
    ...
    "sync_sdk_win/SyncDemo.h",
  ]
  libs = [ "sync_sdk_win/syncDemo.lib" ]`